# Combine three tables including trades, calendars and latest prices to get the daily value of each person's stock portfolio in sql

Tags: sql, join, rows, repeat, stock

I have a sample of stock market data.
There is a buy and sell information table for each person per day per stock.

| person | date | stock | buy_count | sell_count | cumulative(Buy_Sum) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 06-05-2020 | ab | 10 | 0 | 10 |
| a | 06-09-2020 | ab | 15 | 5 | 20 |
| a | 06-15-2020 | ab | 0 | 20 | 0 |
| a | 06-23-2020 | ab | 20 | 0 | 20 |
| a | 06-26-2020 | ab | 0 | 10 | 10 |
| b | 06-05-2020 | cd | 8 | 1 | 7 |
| b | 06-10-2020 | cd | 0 | 7 | 0 |

In the other table there is the daily price of each stock (obviously this table only includes working days, it is also possible that for one day, despite being a working day, there is no price recorded for that stock)

| date | stock | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06-03-2020 | ab | 1 |
| 06-04-2020 | ab | 2 |
| 06-05-2020 | ab | 2.5 |
| 06-08-2020 | ab | 3 |
| 06-09-2020 | ab | 1 |
| 06-10-2020 | ab | 2 |
| 06-11-2020 | ab | 1 |
| 06-12-2020 | ab | 3 |
| 06-15-2020 | ab | 3.5 |
| 06-16-2020 | ab | 4.5 |
| 06-18-2020 | ab | 3 |
| 06-19-2020 | ab | 2 |
| 06-22-2020 | ab | 6 |
| 06-23-2020 | ab | 2.5 |
| 06-24-2020 | ab | 8 |
| 06-25-2020 | ab | 4.5 |
| 06-26-2020 | ab | 6.5 |
| 06-03-2020 | cd | 6 |
| 06-04-2020 | cd | 2.5 |
| 06-05-2020 | cd | 9.5 |
| 06-08-2020 | cd | 7 |
| 06-09-2020 | cd | 10.5 |
| 06-10-2020 | cd | 6 |
| 06-11-2020 | cd | 11 |
| 06-12-2020 | cd | 6.5 |
| 06-15-2020 | cd | 10.5 |
| 06-16-2020 | cd | 8 |
| 06-17-2020 | cd | 12 |
| 06-18-2020 | cd | 5 |
| 06-19-2020 | cd | 17.5 |
| 06-22-2020 | cd | 11.5 |
| 06-23-2020 | cd | 17 |
| 06-24-2020 | cd | 10.5 |
| 06-25-2020 | cd | 17 |
| 06-26-2020 | cd | 9 |

I have a calendar table that shows in one column whether each day is a working day or not.

| date | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 06-03-2020 | working |
| 06-04-2020 | working |
| 06-05-2020 | working |
| 06-06-2020 | NonWorking |
| 06-07-2020 | NonWorking |
| 06-08-2020 | working |
| 06-09-2020 | working |
| 06-10-2020 | working |
| 06-11-2020 | working |
| 06-12-2020 | working |
| 06-13-2020 | NonWorking |
| 06-14-2020 | NonWorking |
| 06-15-2020 | working |
| 06-16-2020 | working |
| 06-17-2020 | working |
| 06-18-2020 | working |
| 06-19-2020 | working |
| 06-20-2020 | NonWorking |
| 06-21-2020 | NonWorking |
| 06-22-2020 | working |
| 06-23-2020 | working |
| 06-24-2020 | working |
| 06-25-2020 | working |
| 06-26-2020 | working |

How can I create a table like this:
As long as a person has a stock in his basket, create a line for it for each day (both working and non-working days) and read the price of that day from the last price in the daily stock price table. In this way, I will have a table containing each person's assets per day and the daily value of his portfolio.

| person | date | date | stock | buy_count | sell_count | cumulative(Buy_Sum) | price | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 06-05-2020 | working | ab | 10 | 0 | 10 | 2.5 | 25 |
| a | 06-06-2020 | NonWorking | ab | 0 | 0 | 10 | 2.5 | 25 |
| a | 06-07-2020 | NonWorking | ab | 0 | 0 | 10 | 2.5 | 25 |
| a | 06-08-2020 | working | ab | 0 | 0 | 10 | 3 | 25 |
| a | 06-09-2020 | working | ab | 15 | 5 | 20 | 1 | 20 |
| a | 06-10-2020 | working | ab | 0 | 0 | 20 | 2 | 40 |
| a | 06-11-2020 | working | ab | 0 | 0 | 20 | 1 | 20 |
| a | 06-12-2020 | working | ab | 0 | 0 | 20 | 3 | 60 |
| a | 06-13-2020 | NonWorking | ab | 0 | 0 | 20 | 3 | 60 |
| a | 06-14-2020 | NonWorking | ab | 0 | 0 | 20 | 3 | 60 |
| a | 06-15-2020 | working | ab | 0 | 20 | 0 | 3.5 | 0 |
| a | 06-23-2020 | working | ab | 20 | 0 | 20 | 2.5 | 50 |
| a | 06-24-2020 | working | ab | 0 | 0 | 20 | 8 | 160 |
| a | 06-25-2020 | working | ab | 0 | 0 | 20 | 4.5 | 90 |
| a | 06-26-2020 | working | ab | 0 | 10 | 10 | 6.5 | 65 |
| b | 06-05-2020 | working | cd | 8 | 1 | 7 | 9.5 | 66.5 |
| b | 06-06-2020 | NonWorking | cd | 0 | 0 | 7 | 9.5 | 66.5 |
| b | 06-07-2020 | NonWorking | cd | 0 | 0 | 7 | 9.5 | 66.5 |
| b | 06-08-2020 | working | cd | 0 | 0 | 7 | 7 | 49 |
| b | 06-09-2020 | working | cd | 0 | 0 | 7 | 10.5 | 73.5 |
| b | 06-10-2020 | working | cd | 0 | 7 | 0 | 6 | 0 |

Comment: Hi - please show the SQL you have already tried and what, in particular, is not working

Comment: hi @NickW . i dont know what should i do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the results:

```
select ps.person, ps.stock, c.date, c.status,
       coalesce(buy_count, 0) as buy_count,
       coalesce(sell_count, 0) as sell_count,
       coalesce(cumulative, 0) as cumulative
from (select distinct person, stock from t) ps cross join
     calendar c left join
     t
     on t.person = ps.person and t.stock = ps.stock and t.date = c.date
order by ps.person, ps.stock, c.date
```

Comment: thank you. But how can I add the latest available price per each day and each stock to the created table?